# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted sometimes

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, sharedpreferences

I have the following code for encrypt

```
public static String encrypt(String value, char[] secret) {
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = value != null ? value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(secret));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(IsoGame.$().crossPlatformManager.getCrossPlatformUtilsInstance().getDeviceUniqueIdentifier().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 20));
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;

    }
```

and the following code for decrypt.

```
public static String decrypt(String value, char[] secret) {
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = value != null ? Base64.decodeBase64(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(secret));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(IsoGame.$().crossPlatformManager.getCrossPlatformUtilsInstance().getDeviceUniqueIdentifier().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 20));
            return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;

    }
```

However, sometimes the exception is being thrown at

```
pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes)
```

in decrypt method.

The exception is `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted`

It's strange, as I'm getting this exception sometimes with the same values .

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to cater for null by using `new byte[0]`, in either direction.mthrow a `NullPointerException`. It's a programming error. You can't decode it so why encode it?

Comment: Hi @user207421. Yup, you are right )

Comment: There seem only two problems, one is  Maarten's suggested reason the other one how you derive the salt. Are you sure `IsoGame...` output always the same?

Comment: @kelalaka The output of  ```IsoGame...``` should be always same. It is my app's bundle id on iOS and the device id on Android. I don't think that it can change just after reopen my app. 
However, I'm experiencing this problem on both platforms. So, I don't think that the problem comes from the ```IsoGame...```.

Comment: So, what is actually sometimes? = 1/5 1/10 etc?

Comment: @kelalaka. Don't know really. But I think, something like 1/500 or so. As I receiving this from the production users and was happy to have this issue yesterday on my end too(first time).

Comment: You should definitely change your encryption. DES? At least use AES-GCM.

Comment: Agree @kelalaka . But the problem is the app is in the production already for about 5 months and there are 50K monthly active users, and they have saved data in their phones' preferences. So, if I'll change the encryption, then they will lose their data)
P.S., but if there is no other way, I'll do that with some work-around) :)

Comment: Also, to check that a user supplied the correct password, you can encrypt a known plaintext and save in internal memory. Before encryption/decryption you can test the password. Note: this method may provide a known-plaintext attack. Addition, there is very fast DES [crackers](https://crack.sh/)

Comment: Hi @GagBaghdasaryan did you find a solution for your query?

Answer (score 5):

The most likely reason would simply be the wrong password to be supplied. If the wrong password is supplied then the wrong key is derived. Then the ciphertext will be decrypted to garbage plaintext. This will only be noticed if the padding exception gets thrown: unpadding random bytes is likely to fail.

You could e.g. first validate that the derived key is correct by performing a HMAC over known data using the derived key. In addition, it would be a good idea to use some kind of authenticated encryption, so that *if* the key or data is wrong or corrupted that decryption does indeed fail. If you're unlucky then - at this time - the data will decrypt, unpadding will succeed and you end up with garbage plaintext.

Of course, you'd better upgrade to PBKDF2 for key derivation, and upgrade AES to e.g. AES-GCM instead of DES. Currently your encryption is entirely insecure, even if you use a strong password.

Comment: Hi. 
Do you mean the char[] secret  is wrong? If so, then it's a constant) 
P.S., I'm using this for Preferences.

Comment: I cannot see what goes wrong as I do see the code, but not the context of the code, the input or the output. However, if you have the gall to still use DES and to return the plaintext instead of the ciphertext on any exception during encryption then I guess all is lost. Heck you could be trying to decipher plaintext all along. Oh wait, if you decrypt plaintext and the padding is *correct* then your method would fail with trash as result. Hah :) If you want a more precise answer, provide failing test values.

Comment: I'm triggered with the sometimes. If there were no base64 encoding that would be the cause. I guess Maarten is right.

Comment: Hmmm.... @MaartenBodewes
For example, the input value for _encrypt()_ is **703** and the result is **dGwO/zHe/Pg=** . Then, I'm experiencing the exception in _decrypt()_ for the **dGwO/zHe/Pg=** value.
P.S., The exception isn't thrown every time for 703 value. Can't reproduce why it's thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is

```java
IsoGame.$().crossPlatformManager.getCrossPlatformUtilsInstance().getDeviceUniqueIdentifier().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

I have ran the following code multiple times and no exception occurred and the decrypted data was equal to "Hello there!":

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CryptographyError();
    }

    private CryptographyError()
    {
        char[] secret = "MySecret".toCharArray();
        String mesasge = "Hello there!";
        EncryptedData encryptedData = encrypt(mesasge, secret);
        System.out.println("ENCRYPTED " + encryptedData.encryptedString);
        String decrypted = decrypt(encryptedData, secret);
        System.out.println("DECRYPTED " + decrypted);
    }

    private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

    public static EncryptedData encrypt(String value, char[] secret) {
        try {
            final byte[] bytes = value != null ? value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(secret));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            RANDOM.nextBytes(salt);
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20));
            return new EncryptedData(salt, new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static String decrypt(EncryptedData encryptedData, char[] secret) {
        try {
            String value = encryptedData.encryptedString;
            byte[] salt = encryptedData.salt;
            final byte[] bytes = value != null ? Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) : new byte[0];
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(secret));
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20));
            return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    private static class EncryptedData
    {
        private final byte[] salt;
        private final String encryptedString;

        private EncryptedData(byte[] salt, String encryptedString)
        {
            this.salt = salt;
            this.encryptedString = encryptedString;
        }
    }
```

The only main difference between my code and your code is

```java
IsoGame.$().crossPlatformManager.getCrossPlatformUtilsInstance().getDeviceUniqueIdentifier().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

which means that must not return the same value on encryption and decryption.
Also if you want to test this you can just change the salt between them and notice the exception is thrown again.

Also Maarten Bodewes gave you some good notes about how to improve your code.

Comment: Very good example, it worked very well here